# Controlling cameras via WiFi only

Tags: wi-fi, video-recording, video-streaming

I am interested in how to make video feeds from non-activated smartphones via WIFI (no 3/4G connection) accessible to a Windows workstation on that same local WIFI network.

I have a need to produce multiple video inputs (similar but not exactly same as multiple home security cameras) and am thinking that using older (cheaper) model smartphones might be able to be tied together via WIFI only. I know there are plenty of remote access access apps out there but i'm needing something to use with WIFI only - the phones will not have a cell carrier plan for 3/4G connectivity.

Ideally there's an app that gives basic control - zoom, start/stop, video/single frame - but it would be enough to just have a way for my network to pull whatever video feeds are present at a given time.

Answer (score 1):

There are many apps on the play store that will do what you’re asking. I know for sure that “IP Webcam” will because I’ve used it myself. Here’s the link:

[IP Webcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam)